# Kaminari undefined method `page' with Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I am using `Kaminari 0.16.3` with `Rails 4.2.0`. Not sure what is going wrong, I have pasted code run by me in console, which proves `kaminari` gem is loaded but `page` method is undefined on `ActiveRecord` model.

```
abhishek@abhishek ~/my_app (master●●)$ rails c                                                                     [ruby-2.1.5p273]
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.0)
irb(main):001:0> Kaminari
=> Kaminari
irb(main):002:0> User.page
NoMethodError: undefined method `page' for User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection):Class
```

**Please note:** I am intentionally calling `page` without any arguments to reproduce the issue.

Comment: I guess `page` should given a value. Try eg: `User.page(1)`

Comment: Try calling `Kaminari.config.page_method_name` to see what you get. If it errors out, try `Kaminari.methods` to see whether it has the config object.

Comment: No errors there. @PrakashMurthy

Comment: Looks more like a `bug` to me.

Comment: What do you get for `Kaminari.config.page_method_name`?

Comment: `:per_page_kaminari` @PrakashMurthy I am not sure if it's possible but you prob. join chat room here -http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84721/discussion-between-athar-and-abhishek77in

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Due to an issue with `will_paginate` and `rails_admin` I had this in my codebase causing the `page` method to be renamed to `per_page_kaminari`.

I have realized this late and fixed.

```
Kaminari.configure do |config|
  config.page_method_name = :per_page_kaminari
end
```

Comment: nice... that is something new to me as well. +1.

Comment: Yes, Prakash got it right. `Kaminari.config.page_method_name` gets me to correct method name to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari

This is how it works

```
 User.page(page_number).per(records_per_page)
```

Comment: I know how it works. Do you see it throws `NoMethodError`. I am not saying I am doing the right thing, but I am saying it's throwing the wrong error.

Comment: try `reload!` and then do that again.

Comment: is it giving each time.? or when you try to fetch the attribute for User.

Comment: can you do simple User in console and tell me what it shows.?

Comment: `=> User (call 'User.connection' to establish a connection)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84721/discussion-between-athar-and-abhishek77in).