# NoMethodError in Admin::PostsController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have done a bundle install for kaminari to enable me to use paginate, but having this exception thrown;

```
undefined method `page' for #<Post::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd6157a9a20> 

Extracted source (around line #3):
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
   def index
     @posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
  end
```

def new

This is the my Posts Controller:

```
class Admin::PostsController < Admin::ApplicationController
  def index
    @posts = Post.all.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
  end
```

This is my **`Admin::Posts#index`**

```
<p><%= link_to 'New Post', new_admin_post_path %></p>

<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>title</th>
            <th>publish</th>
            <th>actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <% @posts.each do |post| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= truncate(post.title, length: 60, separate: '') %></td>
            <td><%= status_converter(post.publish, truthy: 'Active', falsey: 'Pending') %></td>
            <td>
                <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_admin_post_path(post) %> |
                <%= link_to 'Show', admin_post_path(post) %> |
                <%= link_to 'Delete', admin_post_path(post), method: :delete, data: {confirm: 'Are you sure?'} %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>

    </tbody>
</table>
<p><%= paginate @posts %></p>
```

Could you explain why I am having this issue please?

Comment: Please update the question with full error message.

Comment: FYI, This has now been Edited.

Comment: Did you restart rails server after installing kaminari gem?

Comment: @GaneshKunwar, thank you, I restarted and all working efficiently.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729219/kaminari-undefined-method-page-with-rails-4-2 it might help you bro

Answer (score 0):

You can change into this

```
@posts = Post.order(id: :desc).page params[:page]
```

You have to remove `.all` method

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this didn't wrk @Muhamad Akbar Bin Widayat

Answer (score 0):

For your particular use case, I would go for the [ActiveAdmin](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin) gem.