# Undefined method `/` for "":String using Kaminari and Rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I have a rails 6.x JSON API where I am using Kaminari to paginate the results.

My code looks like this:

```rb
module PaginationHelper
  def paginate!(collection)
    collection.page(current_page).per(current_limit)
  end

  def current_page
    params[:page] || 1
  end

  def current_limit
    params[:limit] || 100
  end
end

class TestController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @collection = current_account.test_items
  end
end
```

The error in my view that I keep getting is:

```
"#<NoMethodError: undefined method `/' for \"\":String>"

"trace": "app/controllers/concerns/pagination_helper.rb:3:in `paginate!'"
```

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure if this might be related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31729219/kaminari-undefined-method-page-with-rails-4-2

Comment: Would changing your code to `params[:page].presence&.to_i || 1` and `params[:limit].presence&.to_i || 100` solve the issue?

Comment: @AbM it ended up being in my kaminari config file... `config.default_per_page = ENV.fetch('DEFAULT_PAGINATION_PER_PAGE', 100).to_i` I had removed the `.to_i` on the end of that and it was causing issues